# Cannot chain 2 requests in 1 route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

From my node API I need to call an external API.
For this I use https://github.com/request/request-promise-native

Example route that works:

```
router.get('/update/:id/:value', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await updateMethod(req.params.id, req.params.value);
  res.status(200);
  res.json(result);
});
```

The problem is I don't want to call this route. The update method should be called in another router after a create method:

```
router.post('/create', (req, res, next) => {
  mongo.create(data, async (e, createdEntity) => {
    const saved = await createMethod(someObject);
    const updated = await updateMethod(id, value);
    res.status(200);
    res.json(createdEntity);
    return res;
  }
});
```

So I insert some data in mongo, I POST some data in an external API (inside createMethod) and finally I update / PUT some data to the external API.

Both POST work but the PUT fails with:

> { RequestError: Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:1408E0F4:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_message:unexpected message:openssl\ssl\s3_both.c:408
>
> { method: 'PUT',
>        uri: 'https://externalAPI.com/v1/id/123/value/321',
>        rejectUnauthorized: false,
>        headers:
>         { 'x-api-key': 'xyz',
>           'app-user-id': 'me' },
>        json: true,

The problem is that the exact same PUT method works if I call the route `/update/:id/:value` manually rather then the method from `/create`

This doesn't seem related to how the update method is implemented since it works in the first route:

```
updateMethod = (id, value) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'PUT',
    uri: `${process.env.API_ENDPOINT}/id/${id}/value/${value}`,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': process.env.API_KEY,
      'app-user-id': process.env.API_USER,
    },
    json: true,
  };

  return request(options)
    .then(response => response)
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};
```

I also tried to redirect to the update route with res.redirect but it returns the same error as above. Calling the update route manually works as expected and the external API is updated.

Comment: Can we assume that you shortened `await updateMethod(someOtherObject)` manually for stackoverflow? Because te function needs 2 parameters.

Comment: Also, did i miss something or are you using "await" in a non-async callback-function?

Comment: ah sorry, it's for posting on SO, params and async are set

Comment: @gyc Did you finally find a solution for the issue

Comment: @NickDiv no sorry. I moved on...

Comment: @gyc The issue in my case turned out to the be Server i was sending these requests to. But I am sure you must have figured out something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely chain two requests in Node, and as far as I can tell your code should work.

The error message you posted has to do with SSL - Node for some reason cannot communicate securely with the external API server. That's what you'll need to resolve. You may also try using HTTP instead of HTTPS if the external service allows it.

Comment: ok but why does it work if I call only update in a specific route and not when I chain 2 requests?